# How to change the font size of the editor tabs in Delphi 2010 IDE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Does anybody knows a way to change the font size of the editor tabs in Delphi 2010 IDE? 
With my 1080p 22' monitor the font is too small to read and it causes pain in the eyes.

Some notes

1. It doesn't respect the system's DPI settings so changing that system setting doesn't help, moreover, I'm using 140% DPI already now, and it's Win7.
2. I couldn't find any existing 3rd party tools to tweak that.
3. I'll be willing to write an IDE expert to fix that problem if I know how to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an option to change the font size of these elements, but as you say this can be done writting an expert. Some time ago I started to write an Delphi IDE Expert (This project is not finished yet) which allow you to change the apparence of the Delphi IDE (here you can found the [Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-ide-colorizer/)) , try using some of the code of this project to write your own. Check this image which shows the result of modify the code of the project to increase the font of the `TIDEGradientTabSet`.

[image]

Comment: this is such a great news, I'll check the source out!

Comment: Thank you so much! With your help I was not only able to change the font size of the editor tabs, but also enlarge the font size for the Project Manager and the structure view. (I modified your expert to a new reduced one just for enlarging the font sizes :))

Comment: A slightly less important problem exists though, I couldn't seem be able to change the font size and the *line height* of the "Message" view, it's window class is "TBetterHintWindowVirtualDrawTree". Any hints? (I'll accept your answer, but just to leave it open for a little while so that I'll might also be able to fix this problem related to "Message" view too)

Comment: try dumping the defnition of the `TBetterHintWindowVirtualDrawTree` component,  in the unit [uRttiHelper](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-ide-colorizer/source/browse/trunk/Units/uRttiHelper.pas) exist a method called `DumpTypeDefinition` which uses the RTTI to extract the definition of the components , from here you can see all the availables properties.

Comment: Thanks for the further hint! I'll try it at a later time since that problem is not critical ;)

Comment: Any chance of publishing your expert to enlarge font sizes? The original link no longer works and I can't find any other experts to do this.